# Двусоставное неполное или назывное?

Tags: синтаксис

**Атмосфера - как на ночных нелегальных гонках.**

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, предложение двусоставное, полное. Сравнительный оборот с КАК образует именную часть составного именного сказуемого: атмосфера какова? как на ночных нелегальных гонках.

Comment: Зачем же тогда тире?

Comment: Тире здесь факультативное. Оно может отражать интонационную паузу.